# Problem with MEF import

Tags: wpf, mef, caliburn.micro

I have problem with import class into interfaces in my view model class with MEF.

I view model I create property:

```
    [Import]
    private IEventAggregator EventAgg { get; set; }
```

and I want subcribe this event aggregator in constructor of view model:

So I try this:

```
    public MessengerViewModel()
    {
        EventAgg.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

I run app but app freeze.

So I try subscribe event aggregator in OnImportsSatisfied method:

```
    public void OnImportsSatisfied()
    {
        EventAgg.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

But this method is never calling when is view model class created.

Only solution which work is:

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MessengerViewModel(IEventAggregator eventAggregator)
    {
        EventAgg = eventAggregator;
        EventAgg.Subscribe(this);
    }
```

What is bad in first two ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method will not work because by the time when the constructor gets called the EventAgg dependency is still null.

The second method with `OnImportsSatisfied` should work as long as your view model implements the `IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification` imterface.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't use property (setter) injection on a private property
2. You should implement `IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification` on your ViewModel if you wish MEF to automatically call OnImportsSatisfied